# How to deploy backend and frontend on the same server but different path with Nginx

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I need to deploy the frontend in https://service.domain.it and the backend in https://service.domain.it/api.
I've done a deploy configuration but I'm having troube with spring security + JWT Authentication. This is the configure method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll() //login/logout/recoverypassw
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).
            and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
            and().addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

And this is the nginx configuration

```
#service.domain.it
server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name service.domain.it;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/service.domain.it/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/service.domain.it/privkey.pem;
        location /api/ {
                #backend
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
        }

       location / {
               #frontend
               index index.html;
                alias /var/www/html/Service/;
       }
}
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name service.domain.it;
        return 301 https://service.domain.it$request_uri;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backend service does not understand the `/api` used in your proxy_configuration. You must rewrite the URI before sending it to the backend.

```
location /api {

   rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
   proxy_pass http://backend/;

}
```

This will remove the `/api` from the URI before sending it to the backend.

Comment: Thank you so much. It now works. Honestly I did't think about this configuration

Comment: Great! Would be good if you can mark my coment as the answer. Thanks